# python blackjack game, loop generating new values each time

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

```
def deck():
    cards = range(1, 12)
    return choice(cards)

def player():
    card1 = deck()
    card2 = deck()
    hand = card1 + card2
    print card1, card2
    while hand < 21:
        choice = raw_input("Would you like to hit or stand?: ")
        print choice
        if choice == "hit":
            hand2 = hand + deck()
            print hand2     
        elif choice == "stand": 
                return hand
```

Hello all,

I am trying to make a simple blackjack game in python. I have gotten this far and I seem to be stuck. When I try and play it asks me whether or I want to hit or stand which is good; however, my problem is that it seems to be generating new card values each time. That means if I was to hit and than stand it would return the original value rather than the new value of the three cards.

As you can tell I'm new to programming so any help is appreciated, I'd like to use as much as my own code as possible.

Comment: you really need to make a deck of 52 cards ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then probably 
`hand2 = hand + deck()` inside your `if` is creating  the problem.. You are assigning the sum to the new value, which is not even used anywhere..
You need to update the same `hand`. So replace the above statement with: -

```
hand = hand + deck()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice == "hit":
      hand2 = hand + deck()
      print hand2
```

The "hit" block modifies `hand2` rather than `hand`.

```
if choice == "hit":
      hand += deck()
      print hand
```

Comment: Stupid me. Thank you, its greatly appreciated.